# Can a website detect if the same physical FIDO key is used for multiple accounts?

Tags: security, yubikey, fido2

If I have an account, say with google, and only use that account from location A, using device A, and another google account only used with device B in location B, if I used the same 2fa FIDO key for both accounts, would google have any way of knowing the same key is being used for both accounts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Google doesn’t allow you to tell them what authenticator you will be using, they generate a secret code and a QR code, so your example isn’t possible.  Most websites are the same way.

Answer (score 1):

A website has no way of knowing where the certificate that was used
is physically located on the user's computer, meaning from which device
it was read.

The answer is No.